# How do I manage two separate displays in WPF?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, caliburn.micro

I am writing an application which will allow users to select from a series of maps on a touchscreen display, and then the maps will also display on a larger wall-mounted screen. Users will be able to pan/zoom/rotate around the maps and I would like the wall-mounted screen to show those changes in sync with the touchscreen.

What is a good way to approach managing the two displays?

Currently, I have the application set up in MVVM format and am using Caliburn.Micro.

Each map is in its own UserControl and they are activated in a ContentControl on my ShellView using Conductor and ActivateItem in the ShellViewModel. I would like to have the Active Item also be displayed in a separate Window (on the wall-mounted screen).

Here is the code so far:

ShellView.xaml:

```
    <Grid>
        <!--The Content control shows which MapView is currently active-->
        <ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem"/>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="Select a map.">
                <ComboBox>
                    <Button x:Name="LoadMap1">Map1</Button>
                    <Button x:Name="LoadMap2">Map2</Button>
                    <Button x:Name="LoadMap3">Map3</Button>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

ShellViewModel.cs:

```
    public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<object>
    {
        public ShellViewModel()
        {

        }

        public void LoadMap1()
        {
            ActivateItem(new MapOneViewModel());
        }

        public void LoadMap2()
        {
            ActivateItem(new MapTwoViewModel());
        }

        public void LoadMap3()
        {
            ActivateItem(new MapThreeViewModel());
        }
    }
```

I do not know if this is the best way to set this up, but it works well for loading the maps on the ShellView. I really just need to show the same thing in another window for the wall-mounted Display

Any help appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You can have a look at Caliburn.Micro built-in `WindowManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your monitors are both connected to the same device you can use `Forms.Screen` to get the bounds of each monitor. You then set your windows to the same bounds, add a `Loaded` event handler to maximize them and call `Show()`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var primaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen;
        this.MainWindow = new Window();
        this.MainWindow.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "This is the primary display." };
        this.MainWindow.Left = primaryScreen.Bounds.Left;
        this.MainWindow.Top = primaryScreen.Bounds.Top;
        this.MainWindow.Width = primaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        this.MainWindow.Height = primaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        this.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        this.MainWindow.Loaded += (_s, _e) => this.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        this.MainWindow.Show();

        var secondaryScreen = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens.First(screen => screen != primaryScreen);
        var secondaryWindow = new Window();
        secondaryWindow.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "This is the secondary display." };
        secondaryWindow.Left = secondaryScreen.Bounds.Left;
        secondaryWindow.Top = secondaryScreen.Bounds.Top;
        secondaryWindow.Width = secondaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        secondaryWindow.Height = secondaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        secondaryWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        secondaryWindow.Loaded += (_s, _e) => secondaryWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        secondaryWindow.Show();

    }
}
```